Accessing this server via SQL Management Objects (SMO) or Distributed Management Objects (DMO) is currently not permitted
When I run this,
EXEC SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options', 1
EXEC SP_CONFIGURE 'SMO and DMO XPs', 0

SQL Server management studio unable to connect with error,
Accessing this server via SQL Management Objects (SMO) or Distributed Management Objects (DMO) is currently not permitted.

Interesting thing is that it does not work on 19.3.

But work on 19.1 version,

I updated this as per this blog post,
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/kb4046638-add-the-ability-to-disable-or-enable-a-few-new-dmvs-and-dmfs-introduced-in-sql-server-2017-05d709c5-4522-3168-2cb1-f755fddff9e7
Update: It also stopped https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html
